# bundleContext.getServiceReference in Osgi

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, osgi

I have a problem running a Java application, In the Applet Activator class when it opens 
the gui the bundleContext.getServiceReference throws a NPE, after some search in OSGi It came to me that it happen because there's no service registered that implements the UIService..
my questions is: what does it mean? what should I check to fix it?

error code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.appletActivator.AppletActivator.openMainGui(AppletActivator.java:57)
at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.appletActivator.AppletActivator.start(AppletActivator.java:40)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction$Actions.run(SecureAction.java:1243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:620)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1904)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1822)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

source:

```
public static <T> T getService(BundleContext bundleContext,
        Class<T> serviceClass) {
            //This throws the NullPointerException
    ServiceReference serviceReference = bundleContext 
            .getServiceReference(serviceClass.getName());

    return (serviceReference == null) ? null : (T) bundleContext
            .getService(serviceReference);
}
```

I'm new to OSGi and don't understand some of the concepts.

Comment: It is a bit strange that you say "fails here" in the getService() function while your stack trace points to AppletActivator.openMainGui function as the top. Is it possible that you only copied the top of the exception stacktrace here and not the more important "Caused by" section?

Comment: Sorry I meant that the function call throws the NullPointerException, and OpenMainGui calls the getService..

Comment: and that's the last output of the logger, after that the app stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some bundle installed in the framework that will register the UIService? Also, your code appears that it may be start order sensitive which is a no-no in OSGi. Calling your getService method and expecting it to return a service assumes that the bundle which registers the service has (a) already been started and (b) has registered the service. This is why you normally use DS or ServiceTrackers in OSGi applications to decouple the start order of bundles.

Comment: the UIService is registered and a couple of bundles already get the service reference.

Comment: Yes, but is it registered at the time your bundle attempts to get the service? Are there more than one exporter of the package containing the UIService type? Is your bundle importing and wired to the same package (containing the UIService type) as the bundle registering the service?

Comment: after some digging I found out that the bundle doesn't get registered at time - but how other bundles can call the same method? we are migrating to another code so it opens a lot of problems in OSGi... so the bundle registering the service that I need, I don't need to register it again to use it?

Comment: There are a number of bundles that get started (in some order). Some bundles that want to use the service will get started before the bundle which registers the service and some will get started after the bundle which registers the service. Since you do not want to control the start order, bundle which use services need to not depend upon the services they using being registered during the execution of their BundleActivator. This is why you use Declarative Services or ServiceTrackers to use services.